# mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:/db.php

Tags: mysql

```
     //authentication process starts
      $sel = "SELECT * FROM g_admin WHERE loginname='$ln' AND apassword='$pw'";
      $res = executeQuery($sel);
        echo "kiran  ".$res;
    if(totalRecords($res) == 0){
        echo "Incorrect LoginName/password";    
      }else{
        $rec = getAssoc($res);
        $_SESSION['AdminId'] = $rec['Id'];    
        header("Location: Home.php");
      }
     //authentication process ends 
    }

function executeQuery($qry){
    return mysql_query($qry) or die ('MySQL Not found // Could Not Connectquery.');
}    
function totalRecords($res){
    return mysql_num_rows($res) or die ('MySQL Not found // Could Not Connectres.');
}    
function getAssoc($res){
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($res) or die ('MySQL Not found // Could Not Connectres.');
}

In the above code $res returns 1. But totalRecords($res) thows mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in c:/db.php
```

newly added functions are in db.php
By using those functions we are executing the code.
executeQuery($qry) is working fine and returns result as 1.
next we are calling totalRecords($res), In this case it throws warning.

Comment: You did not post all code, we cannot help like this: where is the definition of function `totalRecords($res)`?

Comment: Basically the error message means that you hand it something that should be a mysql resource handle, but is a boolean. This typically is the case when the query returning the resource handle _failed_ which one has not detected because of missing error detection in the code. But as said: without you posting the rest of the code we cannot say more.

Comment: function executeQuery($qry){
 return mysql_query($qry) or die ('MySQL Not found // Could Not Connectquery.');
}


function totalRecords($res){
 return mysql_num_rows($res) or die ('MySQL Not found // Could Not Connectres.');
}

function getAssoc($res){
 return mysql_fetch_assoc($res) or die ('MySQL Not found // Could Not Connectres.');
}

Comment: Sorry: STOP: please don't post code in comments! Use the `edit` button above to add missing details to the question which is where it belongs.

Comment: Anyway, the additional details clearly show that 1. your query `$sel` throws an error (most likely column or table names are wrong), thus `$res` is `FALSE` and 2. you do not have _any_ error detection towards that, so you try to go on with an invalid resource handle.

Comment: $sel returns correct query. After executing query it returns 1 as $res. But mysql_num_rows($res) throws warning.

Comment: 1. then this is not the real code you post here. Sorry, but a `1` does not magically turn into a `FALSE`. 2. you are using the old, deprecated mysql extension. You should switch to the newer `mysqli` extension or `PDO` and start using "prepared statements". It its current form your code is vulnerable to sql injections which makes it very insecure. Basically an attacker can execute any sql statement without your knowledge most likely including changing and deleting any data.

Comment: I didn't get you. what exactly i have to do?

Comment: If `mysql_num_rows()` complains that `$res` handed over is a boolean and not a handle, then you can rely on the fact that this is the case. So there must be something wrong in the statement that a) the above code is really the code running and b) the query returns a valid handle. This simply _cannot_ be the case according to what you write. So I suggest you start looking closer either by dumping more values (poor mans debugging approach) or, better, start using a debugger (`xdebug`) which allows you to step through your code during the executing and examine all variables values.

Comment: Second point: phps old `mysql` extension is deprecated because it is insecure. There is a newer replacement: `mysqli`, just check the documentation. So instead of using the `mysql_*` commands you should start using the approach of "prepared statements" which does prevent you from exposing your system to "sql injections". You will find all those terms on goole along with many examples. You should be able to understand the idea when you read through the documentation.

Answer (score -3):

**Possible Error**:

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM g_admin WHERE loginname=`'$ln'` AND apassword=`'$pw'`";
```

When using variables in your query, it should be like this...

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM g_admin WHERE loginname='{$ln}' AND apassword='{$pw}'";
```

or

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM g_admin WHERE loginname='".$ln."' AND apassword='".$pw."'";
```

**By the way**

Are you using MySql 5.5? because `mysql_num_rows` extension is deprecated already. better to use `count(*)` in your query instead or use PDO.

Comment: Sorry, but this is simply not true. One certainly can argue if this is good quality code, but it works as posted by the OP.

Comment: Let the OP decide. ^_^

Comment: Still i am getting same warning.

Comment: @yul757 Sorry, but there is nothing to decide. The syntax as posted by the OP does _not_ throw an error, so your statement that this _is_ a (possible) error is simply wrong. This does not help with the real problem at hand. _If_ this would be a syntax problem, the error message would be something totally different and certainly no mysql error.

Comment: SQL statment fails so the mysql_query returns a boolean value (false) instead of a result set. Make sure your query is valid, and focus on it.